# spark sql could not query parquet partitions in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have 100 parquet_dir/*.snappy.parquet files as partitions in AWS s3. File size is 6GB. I could not query these partitioned files. Where the same query was successful when reading same partition files written in HDFS. Knindly suggest me how to deal with this issue.

```
val DF = spark.read.parquet("s3a:/parquet_dir").cache() 
DF.registerTempTable("DF1")
val query1=sqlContext.sql("select * from DF1").show
```

Error message

```
(0 + 24) / 25]2020-04-21 01:08:41,352 WARN storage.BlockManager: Putting block rdd_7_4 failed due to exception java.io.InterruptedIOException: Failed to open s3a://parquet_dir/part-00077-3c1ec48b-611e-4f96-97ed-10f0fe371dd8-c000.snappy.parquet at 4 on s3a://parquet_dir/part-00077-3c1ec48b-611e-4f96-97ed-10f0fe371dd8-c000.snappy.parquet: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool.
2020-04-21 01:08:41,353 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block rdd_7_4 could not be removed as it was not found on disk or in memory
2020-04-21 01:08:41,359 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 4.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 128)
java.io.InterruptedIOException: Failed to open s3a://parquet_dir/part-00077-3c1ec48b-611e-4f96-97ed-10f0fe371dd8-c000.snappy.parquet at 4 on s3a://parquet_dir/part-00077-3c1ec48b-611e-4f96-97ed-10f0fe371dd8-c000.snappy.parquet: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateInterruptedException(S3AUtils.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.reopen(S3AInputStream.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.lambda$lazySeek$1(S3AInputStream.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$2(Invoker.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$3(Invoker.java:260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.lazySeek(S3AInputStream.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.read(S3AInputStream.java:433)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.DelegatingSeekableInputStream.readFully(DelegatingSeekableInputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.DelegatingSeekableInputStream.readFullyHeapBuffer(DelegatingSeekableInputStream.java:127)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.DelegatingSeekableInputStream.readFully(DelegatingSeekableInputStream.java:91)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$ConsecutiveChunkList.readAll(ParquetFileReader.java:1174)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:805)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.checkEndOfRowGroup(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$2.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedRDDBuilder$$anon$1.hasNext(InMemoryRelation.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.$anonfun$doPutIterator$1(BlockManager.scala:1165)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4)!
Tried coalesce of dataframe that read partitioned files and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You've hit the limit on the thread pool and some other operations are taking so long that the waiting thread times out.

Set the option spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.maximum to something larger than the default (48).